# ASP.Net MVC how to invoke the action method every 10 seconds

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Sorry if this is a silly question.

I have a simple MVC action method which retrieves data from database. I would like to call this action method every 10 seconds to get new data.

Basically need a way to refresh the index page, thereby calling the index method, which gets the latest data from db and display it here.

Can anyone help how to do this in asp.net 4.5 mvc EF code first.

This is a simple mvc application.

Thanks

Comment: ASP.NET is request based. You could set up a cron job (linux/mac) or a scheduled job to make a request to the given url every 10 seconds, but i think you would get better suggestions if you told us WHY you want to call it every 10 seconds

Comment: Also worth mentioning where you'll be calling it from.

Comment: this is for a demo purpose to show that whenever there is a message from servicebus queue, there is a process to pickup the message and populate the db. and we retrieve the latest data and display here.

Comment: You can create a partial view and update some parts of your webpage using a similar code as answered by @Bruno Quintela

Comment: thank you. i am new to mvc. can you help with an example code?

Answer (score 0):

If you`re sure that it is what you want to do, you can achieve it using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        callMyAPI();
    }, 10000);
});

function callMyAPI() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'YOUR_URL',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON"
    });
}
```

Comment: Can the url be a mvc url? because i need to show the record in mvc view.

Comment: Sure, you just need to pass the correct Controller name and action name. This is going to call your controller. You need to see what you want to do after that.

Comment: thank you is this setTimeout or setInterval? because i want this to be repeated every 10 seconds